# background of div disappears when scrolling

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to change my site in a way so that all text is in one page instead of different dirs. In the original the partly transparant background of the container div is scrolling along with the page because otherwise the text would scroll over it. The new page is longer so I thought I would set the background to fixed and just redesign it a bit. But now when I scroll at some point the background disappears. I can't find what is causing this. I'm still learning the ins and outs of using divs, so please, if you know what's causing this, explain it to me in words I understand.

Comment: Hi Linda, welcome to StackOverflow! We're more than happy to help you out, and we appreciate that you show us the live version of your site, but could you actually show us some of the code-behind and html? It will greatly help us to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Will do that next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to remove `height: 100%;` from your `#home` element in your css styles.

Comment: that will work.. or if for whatever reason you want to keep 100% height, adding to your #home, overflow:auto will also solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Set the background image to another div (`#back`) rather than to `#home`.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="back"></div>
  <div id="home"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#back{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```